# cannot const qualify type after type trait modification

Tags: c++, types

Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
   typedef typename std::decay<T>::type U;
   const U s;
   Foo(const T& val): s(val) {}
};

template <typename T>
Foo<T> make_foo(const T& val) {
    return Foo<T>(val);
}

int main() {
    make_foo("foo");
}
```

I expect `Foo::s` (or `U`) to be const-ed, but the compiler error I'm getting (on Ubuntu WSL g++ 7.4.0) is

```
bar.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Foo<T>::Foo(const T&) [with T = char [4]]’:
bar.cpp:14:12:   required from ‘Foo<T> make_foo(const T&) [with T = char [4]]’
bar.cpp:18:19:   required from here
bar.cpp:9:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘Foo<char [4]>::U {aka char*}’ [-fpermissive]
    Foo(const T& val): s(val) {}
                            ^
```

which obviously means that neither `U` or `Foo::s` is a `const char*`. Thoughts?

**EDIT**:

For anyone running into this problem, the solution is exactly as StoryTeller points out in his post below. In other words, the `const` I had in `make_foo(const T& val)` in the parameter signature was stripping the const from the type parameter and making `T` evaluate to `char [4]`. And for some reason, I couldn't even grasp putting a `const` in the template angle brackets of each instance of `Foo<...>` (the return type and the expression returned):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
   static_assert(std::is_same<T, const char[4]>::value);
   typedef typename std::decay<T>::type U;
   static_assert(std::is_same<U, const char*>::value);
   U s;
   Foo(const T& val): s(val) {}
};

template <typename T>
Foo<const T> make_foo(const T& val) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, char[4]>::value);
    return Foo<const T>(val);
}

int main() {
    make_foo("foo");
}
```

Also, as chris pointed out as well, it's nice to spam `static_assert` and `std::is_same` to make dealing with templates in combination with `const` a bit more sane.

Comment: `U` is a `const` pointer to a (non-`const`) `char` (aka `char *const`). `const U` is the same as `U`, because `U` is already `const`. This could be counterintuitive, but it makes sense if you think about it.

Comment: @Chipster oh whoops, meant to remove `#include <string>` to make things a bit more clear. Right, I meant for "foo" to be `const char*` (but really I guess it's `const char[4]` before the compiler gets to the ctor)

Comment: So, in other words, just to be clear, what I want is to make `U` (and thus `Foo::s`) const, but the compiler keeps saying `U` is not const. I even tried putting about 5 more consts next to `const U s`

Comment: It is const, but the const placement is misleading you. Does it make more sense if one writes it as `U const s;` instead? Remember it's exactly the same declaration.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yeah I understand it's const. Tell that to the compiler error...

Comment: In other words, in the error message, it says `U {aka char*}`

Comment: The word *"obviously"* is often used to mean "*I don't understand this, so this is what I want to be true"*, as in "which obviously means that neither `U` or `Foo::s` is const." Rather, the message means that neither `U` nor `Foo::s` is **a pointer to** a constant.

Comment: Here's as far as I understand: (1) make_foo() happens and `T` is deduced to `const char[4]` per the immutable string literal. (2) `const char[4] val` gets forwarded to the Foo ctor where `T` is still `const char[4]`. (3) Per the typedef, `const char[4]` (`T`) is decayed to `const char*` (pointer to const char) then, `std::add_const` makes it redundantly `const`, thus making `U` `const char*`. (4) `const U s` declaration evaluates to `const char* s` even with all the redundant const-ing. (5) `const T& val` in the ctor signature evaluates to `const char[4]& val`...

Comment: In other words, on the initialization of `s` in the ctor, I figured it'd be `const char[4]` being assigned to `const char*`, but that doesn't appear to be the case based on the error message

Comment: @solstice333 On step (3), adding `std::add_const` is not redundant. The result should be `const char * const`, which is different than `const char *`. In the former case, the pointer cannot be assigned a new value, while in the latter it can. (In both cases, the pointed-to value cannot be assigned a new value.)

Comment: @JaMiT Ah, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I've modified the code in the OP to make it so `U` evaluates to what I think should be `const char*`

Comment: @solstice333, [You don't have to guess](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xp3whz). The compiler can check for you.

Comment: @chris thanks. Yeah, I'll do that (spam `static_assert` and `std::is_same`) from now on to keep my sanity

Comment: @chris the only downside to that, is that there's no easy way to print out the actual type information that the static assert fails, at least not for c++11 AFAIK

Comment: @solstice333, Yeah, there are tricks to print types (usually as part of error messages, such as an undefined `template<typename T> void print_type();`), but nothing standard until reflection comes around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make_foo` accepts by a `const T &`, and you pass in a constant array of 4 characters (that's what string literals are). Template argument deduction must therefore match a `const char (&)[4]` against the `const T &`. And since the const is specified in the parameter type, that leaves `T` as `char[4]`. The const qualifier is "consumed" by the function parameter.

So when you instantiated `Foo<T>`, you did so with `char[4]`. That type will decay to a `char*`, not a `const char*`. Adding `const` on top of it will only produce a `char * const`.

If you wish to preserve the const-ness of `T`, then amend your return statement (and type) to be

```
return Foo<const T>(val);
```

Comment: Ah, I see. The consumption of the `const` is certainly obvious now in hindsight. Yeah, I'm an idiot. Thanks for the help. Let me try some things out.